# Confusion regarding ROC

Tags: model-evaluation, roc

I am studying ROC for model evaluation for the first time and I have two questions that are confusing me :

1. I totally understand how to construct ROC with a logistic regression model, in which for every threshold we compute the true and false positive rates. This makes sense with logistic regression as logistic regression calculates probabilities and then to get the final value we need a crisp value and we do so by selecting a threshold. However, this doesn't make sense with models like decision tree , random forests , support vector machine and so on, as where is the threshold in these models ?? For example in decision tree we use splits with for example Gini criteria. So in general, how ROC can be interpreted with any model other than logistic regression ?
2. From ROC we can calculate AUC, which is the area under the ROC curve. If we have two models, we select one the model with the higher AUC. Why ? Because higher area means that we can find points  where the true positive rate is larger and the false positive rate is smaller than the model with the smaller AUC. Is that correct ?

Comment: How does a random forest decide on the category to which it classifies an observation?

Comment: @Dave I think I got it. The threshold in random forest is the threshold used when we get the votes from the decision trees that form the random forest ? So if we have 10 decision trees and 2 classes and if 4 of them votes for the first class and the rest votes for the second class, then p(first class) = 4/10 and p( second class) = 6/10 and then we can use different threshold values to get the final classification ? Is that correct ?

Comment: @Dave And for the descion tree , the threshold is used when an observation ends up in a certain leave and then p( class 1) = number of points labeled as class 1 / total number of points in the leave  and in a similar manner p ( class 2 ) =  number of points labeled as class 2 / total number of points in the leave, then we use a threshold to calculate the final prediction ? Is that also correct for decision tree ?